# How to change the icon with a state only in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating reusable react accordion component and need to change the icon of the menu. First, arrow right icon should be displayed when button is inactive and when user clicks on it, list of links should be displayed and icons should get changed to arrow down.

So far I mananged to make it diplaying, but not after I click on the menu both of them are displying together instead of change.

I am using storybook for displaying, styled components for styles. Here is the code and how they look so far in storybook:

````
import { string, oneOf, func, bool } from "prop-types"
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Icon, { icons } from "design-system/components/icon"
import * as Styled from "./Button.styled"

const Button = ({href,text,iconactive,iconinactive,variant,color,size,
}) => {
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
const [isinActive, setIsInActive] = useState(false);
return (
  <Styled.Component
  color={color}
  size={size}
  >
    <Styled.Text
    variant={variant}
    color={color}
    size={size}
    href={href}
    onClick={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}>
      {text}
    </Styled.Text>
    {isActive && <Styled.Icon>
        <Icon name={iconactive} size={size} color={color}/>
    </Styled.Icon>}
    >
    {isinActive &&
     <Styled.Icon>
        <Icon name={iconinactive} size={size} color={color}/>
    </Styled.Icon>}
    {isActive && <Styled.Links size={size} color={color}>
      {href} {href}
      </Styled.Links>}
  </Styled.Component>
);
};

Button.propTypes = {
  text: string.isRequired,
  href: string,
  iconactive: oneOf(Object.keys(icons)),
  variant: oneOf(["fill", "border", "text", "textLine"]),
  color: oneOf(["primary", "black", "white"]),
  size: oneOf(["small", "medium", "large"]),
  active: bool,
  onClick: func,
}

Button.defaultProps = {
  href: null,
  iconactive: null,
  isinActive: null,
  variant: "fill",
  color: "primary",
  size: "medium",
  active: null,
  onClick: null,
}


export default Button

storybook:

import { Meta, Canvas, Story, ArgsTable } from "@storybook/addon-docs"

import Button from "design-system/components/button"
import Icon from "design-system/components/icon"

<Meta title="Components/Button" component={Button} />

# Button

Button can be a regular button, a link or a navigation link.

<Canvas>
  <Story
    name="Overview - button icon end"
    args={{
      text: "Inactive",
      iconactive: "arrowdown",
      iconinactive: "arrowright",
      variant: "fill",
      size: "small",
      href: "Link",
    }}
  >
    {Template.bind()}
  </Story>
    {Template.bind()}
  </Story>
</Canvas>

<ArgsTable />

export const Template = (args) => <Button {...args} />

Button Styled:

import styled from "@emotion/styled"
import theme from "design-system/theme"

const sizes = {
  small: {
    typography: theme.typography.desktop.bodySmall,
    padding: "8px 32px",
  },
  medium: {
    typography: theme.typography.desktop.h5,
    padding: "10px 40px",
  },
  large: {
    typography: theme.typography.desktop.h4,
    padding: "12px 48px",
  },
}

const colors = {
  primary: {
    mainColor: theme.colors.primary[500],
    filledText: theme.colors.neutrals[100],
  },
  black: {
    mainColor: theme.colors.grey[600],
    filledText: theme.colors.neutrals[100],
  },
  white: {
    mainColor: theme.colors.neutrals[100],
    filledText: theme.colors.primary[300],
  },
}

export const Component = styled.a`
  ${({ size }) => sizes[size].typography};
  letter-spacing: -0.02em;
  border-radius: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: ${({ size }) => sizes[size].padding};
  
`
export const Text = styled.span`
color: ${({ variant, color }) =>
variant === "fill" ? colors[color].mainColor : "black"};
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  width: 342px;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}`

export const Icon = styled.span`
color: ${({ variant, color }) =>
variant === "fill" ? colors[color].mainColor : "black"};
`
export const Links = styled.span`
display: block;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: flex-start;
padding: 5px;
${({ size }) => sizes[size].typography};
letter-spacing: -0.02em;
gap: 3rem;
border-radius: 30px;
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration: none;
padding: ${({ size }) => sizes[size].padding};
color: ${({ variant, color }) =>
  variant === "fill" ? colors[color].filledText : "black"};
`


```[![here state is inactive][1]][1]
[![here state is active][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHrGQ.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikite.png


Could you please be so kind to advsie how could I implement the change of the icon over click in this componennt ?

Thank you in advance,

regards,
Emilia
````

Comment: please add your `Button.styled` file

Answer (score 0):

You are using too many states!!!

It's better to get rid of the `isinActive` state and only use `isActive`. Think of it as a switch that toggles between on and off.

Your component could also be rearranged like this:

```
import { string, oneOf, func, bool } from "prop-types"
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Icon, { icons } from "design-system/components/icon"
import * as Styled from "./Button.styled"

const Button = ({
  href,
  text,
  iconactive,
  iconinactive,
  variant,
  color,
  size,
}) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const currentIcon = isActive ? iconactive : iconinactive;
  return (
    <Styled.Component
      color={color}
      size={size}
    >
      <Styled.Text
      variant={variant}
      color={color}
      size={size}
      href={href}
      onClick={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}>
        {text}
      </Styled.Text>
      <Styled.Icon>
          <Icon name={currentIcon} size={size} color={color}/>
      </Styled.Icon>
      {isActive && (
        <Styled.Links size={size} color={color}>
          {href} {href}
        </Styled.Links>
      )}
    </Styled.Component>
  );
}

Button.propTypes = {
  text: string.isRequired,
  href: string,
  iconactive: oneOf(Object.keys(icons)),
  variant: oneOf(["fill", "border", "text", "textLine"]),
  color: oneOf(["primary", "black", "white"]),
  size: oneOf(["small", "medium", "large"]),
  active: bool,
  onClick: func,
}

Button.defaultProps = {
  href: null,
  iconactive: null,
  isinActive: null,
  variant: "fill",
  color: "primary",
  size: "medium",
  active: null,
  onClick: null,
}

export default Button
```

About the storybook.
I haven't really worked with storybooks, but I hope this helps.

According to [this link](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/get-started/whats-a-story) from its documentation, you need to make sure the file has the mdx extension: `Button.stories.mdx`.

Also, it looks that you need to do some changes in the code:

```
import { Meta, Canvas, Story, ArgsTable } from "@storybook/addon-docs"

import Button from "design-system/components/button"
import Icon from "design-system/components/icon"

<Meta title="Components/Button" component={Button} />

<!-- Define this template above the story -->
export const Template = (args) => <Button {...args} />

# Button

Button can be a regular button, a link or a navigation link.

<Canvas>
  <Story
    name="Overview - button icon end"
    args={{
      text: "Inactive",
      iconactive: "arrowdown",
      iconinactive: "arrowright",
      variant: "fill",
      size: "small",
      href: "Link",
    }}
  >
    <!-- Pass an empty object to the template bind -->
    {Template.bind({})}
  </Story>
</Canvas>

<ArgsTable />
```

Comment: This one looks good, but could you please help in storybok as well? Why  component is not diplaying?